# setDT instead of as.data.table for piping with dplyr?

Tags: r, data.table, tibble, dtplyr

I've noted that `dtplyr` (released this January 1.0.1) uses `as.data.table` to bring the variable back to `data.table` type: https://dtplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/translation.html

I'm a big fan and user of data.table and use it pipeline with dplyr for many years, for which purpose I wrote myself many of those wrapper functions, which are now part of `dtplyr`.

I'm however using `setDT`, as I thought it's more efficient as keeps with  data.table mentality of assigning by reference.

So I wonder why Hadley is not using it?
And in general - what's more efficient to use of the two, when one needs to convert from data.frame (or tibble) to data.table?

Comment: as.data.table is used because it guarantees a copy is made of the input object; in general this would be slower than setDT, but tidyverse principles require immutability & so avoid changing the input object. IIRC there is an option to disable this, I forget the value off the top of my head, you can check the vignette